# Compare an array with another & then return the index of matched results

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, compare

Sorry if this is a dumb question but everything I try seems to be wrong! (I am new to Swift).

I have 2 arrays of Strings which I need to compare for matches and then return an array with the index position of those matches .... IE:

```
let array1 = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "xyz", "uhr"]
let array2 = ["ghi", "xyz", "uhr"]

// Search array1 for instances of array2

// Result I want is: [2, 4, 5]
```

Is there a simple function I am missing?! Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `let result = array2.map({ array1.firstIndex($0) ?? -1 })` or `let result2 = array2.compactMap({ array1.firstIndex(of: $0) })` ? It's missing cases: What happen if you have twice `"ghi"` in `array1` ? What happen if you don't have `"ghi"` in `array1` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help pal - in this case the values in Array 1 will always be unique. Your 2nd point does raise a question though ....  I guess there could be an occasion where array 2 could be ["ghi", "xyz", "uhr", "zzz"] - in this case "zzz" does not exist in Array 1 & ideally I need it to be ignored ....

Comment: Then compactMap and firstIndex(of:) should work fine

Comment: `result2` is the the "shortest" way to do so using "basic" methods with closures. But if you are starting as a developer (and not only a Swift), there is no issue about doing yourself a manual for or foreach loop to get some basic algorithmic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an efficient solution you can create an *index* first. The index maps each element in the first array to its position in the array. Both arrays are traversed only once:

```
let array1 = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "xyz", "uhr"]
let array2 = ["ghi", "xyz", "uhr"]

let index = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: array1.enumerated().map {
    ($0.element, $0.offset)
})
let result = array2.compactMap { index[$0] }
print(result) // [2, 4, 5]
```

If the elements in `array1` are not known to be unique then the index must be computed slightly differently:

```
let index = Dictionary(array1.enumerated().map { ($0.element, $0.offset) },
                       uniquingKeysWith: { (first, _) in first })
```

The second parameter is a closure which controls which value to put into the dictionary in the case of duplicate keys. Here we choose the position of the first occurrence of an element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var indexArr: [Int] = []

for element in array2 {
    if let elementIndex = array1.firstIndex(of: element) {
       indexArr.append(elementIndex)
    }
}

print(indexArr)
```

Comment: I ended up going with this one but in fairness they all worked! Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var results: [Int] = []

for i in 0..<array1.count {
   for j in 0..<array2.count {
      if array1[i] == array2[j] {
         results.append(i)
      }
   }
}

print(results)
```